# Default .htaccess files and Apache 2.4 compatibility

Tags: htaccess, apache

I was just setting up a new site (2.11.2) and noticed (for the first time, I guess) that there are a few .htaccess files at various places in the code tree. They're quite simple, just a single line "Deny from all".
I'm on Apache 2.4, however, and that syntax is no longer valid. For Apache 2.4 the statement should be "Require all denied".
Has anybody ever had an issue with this?
I have a number of sites that have recently been moved onto newer servers and have gone from an Apache 2.2.x environment to one of Apache 2.4.x. I haven't seen any problems anywhere that are obvious, but I haven't really been looking for them.
Anybody out there bumped into this yet?

Many thanks,

Andy